# coalesce.go:163: warning: skipped value for initContainers: Not a table

Tags: helm3

helm template .
coalesce.go:163: warning: skipped value for initContainers: Not a table.
Error: YAML parse error on xray/templates/xray-statefulset.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 48: did not find expected key

Use --debug flag to render out invalid YAML

I am using the below helm chart

https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/jfrog/xray/103.51.0

Comment: What command did you run that led to that error message?